# How to configure structure map if one parameter needs to be manually passed and the second needs to be resolved

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, structuremap

I am facing a scenario where my view is a Windows Form so once its constructor is called I want to create an instance of the `Presenter` class. My presenter has a constructor that takes two arguments, one is the view and the second is the repository like this:

`Presenter(IView, IRepository)`

Now ideally I want the view to pass itself in the first parameter but let StructureMap inject the second parameter. 
So from my view I want to call another constructor of Presenter class with one parameter

`Presenter(IView)`

and somehow tell structure map to resolve the repository.

I am not sure if this is possible? Has anyone faced a scenario like this and if so how do we handle it without creating a dependency on the DI framework?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your best bet is to inject an instance of your StructureMap `IContainer` into your Windows Form, then resolve your `Presenter` class like so (where the `viewParam` string is the name of your parameter on your `Presenter` class):

```
...
    public Form(IContainer container)
    {
        IPresenter presenter = container.With("viewParam").EqualTo(new YourView()).GetInstance<IPresenter>();
    }
...
```

StructureMap should then automatically resolve the dependency on the `IRepository` parameter if you've configured it to do so.

**Edit**

Another option is to create a builder class and inject that instead. A builder class is much like a factory class that's often used when the dependency you're creating requires a little more customisation that falls outside of the boundary of StructureMap. [See this answer for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27862078/963542).

Comment: Thanks Joe for your input, yes to me this seems like the last option. If that is the only option in this case than wouldn't it be better if I abstract the DI container via my own interface and call something like IResolveDependencies.GetInstanceOf<IPresenter>()?

This way the actual DI container would be abstracted and can be replace with any framework.

Comment: Yes, this is certainly another possibility. One option I was going to mention was injecting a builder class. See my updated answer for more information.

Comment: Thanks, I guess this would be the best solution in the current context.